# How to disable colored lines in Sublime Text 3 gutter?

Tags: text-editors, sublime-text-3

After my Sublime Text 3 received an update some time ago, it started to show weird colored lines in the gutter area:

[image]

[image]

How do I get rid of them?

FYI I already have `"show_git_status": false` in my user preferences file.

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out. Needed to add `"mini_diff": false` to the user settings.

Comment: WTF don't they provide an option to disable this without hacking a settings file?!